# Debian kernel kills my program

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

I have a java program that needs to be continuously run on a Linux Virtual private server. It works fine but after several minutes it gets terminated with a message "Killed." I have plenty of memory available so this does not look like an Out of Memory.

```
MemTotal:         262144 kB
MemFree:          140412 kB
Cached:            66472 kB
SwapTotal:        524288 kB
SwapFree:         517216 kB
```

How do I figure out the underlying issue? How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you running it as a background 'daemon'?  Does it die when you log out?  How long does it run before dying?  Does this particular class of virtual server have any automatic log-out processes?  We'll need much more information, specifics, to be able to help.  Where does it say 'killed"?  stdout? stderr? a log somewhere (YOUR code may not log, but java runs on a virtual machine itself, which WILL log things.) What phase of the moon is required?

Answer (score 1):

Run `ulimit -a` and see if there are any limits that you might be hitting, then change them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs of the Java program, which should give you some clues.  Look in the directory where you installed it for a `logs` directory or similar.

Comment: The program is a one written by me and it does not generate any logs since the process is terminated externally.

Comment: Check `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/dmesg`, and `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: if you are the authore of the program and it doesn't generate any logs, then it is probably time to start implementing a log-facility. a daemon should always be able to log somewhere, in case there is trouble...